# Xamarin Studio: disable code completion?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I would like to turn off all code completion in Xamarin Studio, so that nothing at all appears on screen apart from the characters I've typed.

I also want (if it's a separate issue) to disable the tooltips that appear if you leave the mouse cursor over a word.

After considerable searching, I can't find any settings that seem to correspond to either of these things.  I gather `MonoDevelop` has a straightforward `enable auto-completion` checkbox, but if there's anything like that in Xamarin it's well hidden (or I'm particularly dense).

---

Edited to add:

On further research, it seems MonoDevelop has a property `EnableCodeCompletion` in its XML config file, but adding this property to Xamarin's config, with `value="false"`, doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio are you using?

Comment: It's version 5.10.3 (the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

Update: It appears that disabling code completion is "broken" in the code:

- main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion/CSharpCompletionTextEditorExtension.cs

---

```
public override Task<ICompletionDataList> HandleCodeCompletionAsync (CodeCompletionContext completionContext, char completionChar, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
                {
//                      if (!EnableCodeCompletion)
//                              return null;
                        if (!IdeApp.Preferences.EnableAutoCodeCompletion && char.IsLetter (completionChar))
                                return null;

                        //      var timer = Counters.ResolveTime.BeginTiming ();
                        try {
```

---

So the basic code competition check is skipped (commented out) and the second check ignores the pref. setting if a "letter" is typed. If you only type numbers than no code completion windows comes up ;-)

---

It is `EnableAutoCodeCompletion`:

Within `Preferences` \ `TextEditor` \ `Code Completion` , unselect "Show completion list after a character is typed"....

[image]

```
~/Library/Preferences/XamarinStudio-6.0/MonoDevelopProperties.xml
```

---

```
<Property key="EnableAutoCodeCompletion" value="False" />
```

---

Comment: I did have EnableAutoCodeCompletion turned off, but all that does is restrict it to showing the popup when you hit space etc., rather than doing it on every single character...

Comment: `EnableAutoCodeCompletion is false` is going to stop it from popping up only on the first member being typed, i.e. after you type a period, code completion is enabled. You want to be able to set `EnableCodeCompletion` to false, but as I showed, that is commented out of the code currently... fill a bug report at bugzilla.xamarin.com and/or do a pull-request on the github repo.

Comment: Can I ask what github repo you're looking at (e.g. for the code quoted above)?  If it's possible to build my own fork of Xamarin Studio I'm willing to give that a try.

Comment: The is Xamarin/Mono's `MonoDevelop` repo on Github @ http://github.com/mono/monodevelop `Xamarin Studio` is a superset that includes the MonoDevelop base